# Как добавить дату и время создания листа?

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, pandas, dataframe

Есть метод вывода результатов работы программы в excel:

```
def append_df_to_excel(self, df, sheet_name='Sheet1', startrow=None,
                       truncate_sheet=False,
                       **to_excel_kwargs):
    from openpyxl import load_workbook
    if 'engine' in to_excel_kwargs:
        to_excel_kwargs.pop('engine')
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter('D:\\git\\validator\\reports\\Errors.xlsx', engine='openpyxl')
    try:
        writer.book = load_workbook('D:\\git\\validator\\reports\\Errors.xlsx')
        if startrow is None and sheet_name in writer.book.sheetnames:
            startrow = writer.book[sheet_name].max_row
        if truncate_sheet and sheet_name in writer.book.sheetnames:
            idx = writer.book.sheetnames.index(sheet_name)
            writer.book.remove(writer.book.worksheets[idx])
            writer.book.create_sheet(sheet_name, idx)
        writer.sheets = {ws.title: ws for ws in writer.book.worksheets}
    except FileNotFoundError:
        pass
    if startrow is None:
        startrow = 2
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name, startrow=startrow, **to_excel_kwargs)
    writer.save()
```

Результат выглядит примерно так:

[image: Вот что выводится]

А возможно ли добавить справа/снизу/сверху от таблицы дату и время создания листа?

Comment: вы хотите добавлять дату/время в момент записи DataFrame? Проще всего было бы добавить дату/время к названию листа (`sheet`)

Comment: Тоже как варинт

Answer (score 3):

Проще всего было бы добавить дату/время к названию листа (`sheet`):

```
append_df_to_excel('d:/temp/1.xlsx', df, 
                   sheet_name='Sheet1_{}'.format(pd.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H%M%S')))
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

PS [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38075046) можно найти новую версию функции `append_df_to_excel ()`

Comment: и всё же интересно, каким образом это можно печатать вместе с df?

Comment: @ФедорАндреевичПривалов, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17299364/insert-row-into-excel-spreadsheet-using-openpyxl-in-python